# app.component.ts:65 DELETE http://localhost:3000/employees/$%7Bid%7D 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

```
deleteemployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
return this._http.delete('http://localhost:3000/employees/${id}');
```

}
}

error:HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:3000/employees/$%7Bid%7D', ok: false, …}
error
:
{}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/employees/$%7Bid%7D: 404 Not Found"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
url
:
"http://localhost:3000/employees/$%7Bid%7D"
[[Prototype]]
:
HttpResponseBase

Answer (score 0):

to use the `${}` syntax, you have to use backquotes instead of quotes:

```
return this._http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/employees/${id}`);
```